# Fuzzy matching (not row-to-row) in R

Tags: r, string-matching, fuzzy-search

I need to do fuzzy matching in a following pattern: table A contains strings with addresses (already preformatted by me like removing whitespaces etc.), which I have to verify their correctness. I have table B which contains all the possible addresses (formatted in same shape as table A), so I don't want to just match row 1 from table A to row 1 from table B and so on, but compare each row from table A to the whole table B and find the closest match for each.

From what I have checked, `adist` and `agrep` work on row-to-row basis by default, by trying to use them I also immediately get out of memory message. Is it even possible to do in R while having 8 GB RAM only?

I have found an example code for a similar problem and based my solution on it, but performance is still issue. It works fine on a sample of 600 rows in table A and 2000 rows in table B, but the complete dataset is 600000 and 900000 rows, respectively.

```
adresy_odl <- adist(TableA$Adres, TableB$Adres, partial=FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE)
min_odl<-apply(adresy_odl, 1, min)

match.s1.s2<-NULL  
for(i in 1:nrow(adresy_odl))
{
  s2.i<-match(min_odl[i],adresy_odl[i,])
  s1.i<-i
  match.s1.s2<-rbind(data.frame(s2.i=s2.i,s1.i=s1.i,s2name=TableB[s2.i,]$Adres, s1name=TableA[s1.i,]$Adres, adist=min_odl[i]),match.s1.s2)
}
```

The memory error happens already at the first row (adist function):

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1897.0 Gb
```

Below is example (CSV) of data I use, tableA and tableB look exactly the same, the only difference is that tableB has all the possible combinations of Zipcode, Street and City, while in tableA there are mostly either wrong zipcodes or some errors in spelling of streets.

TableA:

```
"","Zipcode","Street","City","Adres"
"33854","80-221","Traugutta","Gdańsk","80-221TrauguttaGdańsk"
"157093","80-276","KsBernardaSychty","Gdańsk","80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk"
"200115","80-339","Grunwaldzka","Gdańsk","80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk"
"344514","80-318","Wąsowicza","Gdańsk","80-318WąsowiczaGdańsk"
"355415","80-625","Stryjewskiego","Gdańsk","80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk"
"356414","80-452","Kilińskiego","Gdańsk","80-452KilińskiegoGdańsk"
```

TableB:

```
"","Zipcode","Street","City","Adres"
"47204","80-180","11Listopada","Gdańsk","80-18011ListopadaGdańsk"
"47205","80-041","3BrygadySzczerbca","Gdańsk","80-0413BrygadySzczerbcaGdańsk"
"47206","80-802","3Maja","Gdańsk","80-8023MajaGdańsk"
"47207","80-299","Achillesa","Gdańsk","80-299AchillesaGdańsk"
"47208","80-316","AdamaAsnyka","Gdańsk","80-316AdamaAsnykaGdańsk"
"47209","80-405","AdamaMickiewicza","Gdańsk","80-405AdamaMickiewiczaGdańsk"
"47210","80-425","AdamaMickiewicza","Gdańsk","80-425AdamaMickiewiczaGdańsk"
"47211","80-456","AdolfaDygasińskiego","Gdańsk","80-456AdolfaDygasińskiegoGdańsk"
```

First few rows of my code results:

```
"","s2.i","s1.i","s2name","s1name","adist"
"1",1333,614,"80-152PowstańcówWarszawskichGdańsk","80-158PowstańcówWarszawskichGdańsk",1
"2",257,613,"80-180CzerskaGdańsk","80-180ZEUSAGdańsk",3
"3",1916,612,"80-119WojskiegoGdańsk","80-355BeniowskiegoGdańsk",8
"4",1916,611,"80-119WojskiegoGdańsk","80-180PorębskiegoGdańsk",6
"5",181,610,"80-204BraciŚniadeckichGdańsk","80-210ŚniadeckichGdańsk",7
"6",181,609,"80-204BraciŚniadeckichGdańsk","80-210ŚniadeckichGdańsk",7
"7",21,608,"80-401alGenJózefaHalleraGdańsk","80-401GenJózefaHalleraGdańsk",2
"8",1431,607,"80-264RomanaDmowskiegoGdańsk","80-264DmowskiegoGdańsk",6
"9",1610,606,"80-239StefanaCzarnieckiegoGdańsk","80-239StefanaCzarnieckiegoGdańsk",0
```

Comment: Yes, you can use an `apply` function to vectorize either of the functions you mentioned across an entire data frame.  Can you share any code with us here?

Comment: There's no way of knowing unless you post some data, we suggest some code, and you try it on 8GB machine.

Comment: Added my code in the opening post. The memory error happens already in the first line (calculating the adist).

Comment: Please add anonymized example data to your question (just a few rows :-) TXH

Comment: Added an example (table exported from R to CSV, apologise it doesn't look as clear as normal table, but I think it's simple enough not to matter).

Comment: THX for the first example data of tableA. Please note that SO works by posting a minimal reproducible example (code + data + expected result) to reduce the efforts for us to answer your question. So I am asking you again to add (more) data please: tableB - we do not have the time to construct example data for each and every question. THX for understanding this and helping us :-)

Comment: The memory problem is caused by `adist` which returns a matrix (n * m = 600,000 * 9,000,000 !) with distance values for each combination. `adist` is not good without identifying a small number of rows for `tableB` as good matching candidates. I think you (or us ;-) need another strategy to find duplicates...

Comment: Sorry for this, I am new to this site, I hope now everything should be clear (added TableB and result generated by my code). Do you think some prefiltering of data (for example, splitting it by city then running adist separately for each city) would be reasonable in terms of performance or should I look for a completely different approach to the problem?

Comment: Or another idea - instead of trying to calculate this whole enormous matrix at once, doing it row-by-row and immediately only leaving the minimal value  while dropping the rest, this means that we get 1x600k instead of 900kx600k matrix. It sounds like opposite of vectorization, and, judging from my not too big experience with R, this might kill the performance of the code though.

Comment: @PrzeM Can you try the footprint of `fuzzyjoin` in my solution below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try awesome `fuzzyjoin` package by @drob of StackOverflow

```
library(dplyr)

dict_df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~ID,~Zipcode,~Street,~City,~Adres,
"33854","80-221","Traugutta","Gdańsk","80-221TrauguttaGdańsk",
"157093","80-276","KsBernardaSychty","Gdańsk","80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk",
"200115","80-339","Grunwaldzka","Gdańsk","80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk",
"344514","80-318","Wąsowicza","Gdańsk","80-318WąsowiczaGdańsk",
"355415","80-625","Stryjewskiego","Gdańsk","80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk",
"356414","80-452","Kilińskiego","Gdańsk","80-452KilińskiegoGdańsk") %>% 
  select(ID, Adres)

    noise_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Zipcode,~Street,~City,~Adres,
  "80-221","Trauguta","Gdansk","80-221TraugutaGdansk",
  "80-211","Traugguta","Gdansk","80-211TrauggutaGdansk",
  "80-276","KsBernardaSychty","Gdańsk","80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk",
  "80-267","KsBernardaSyschty","Gdańsk","80-276KsBernardaSyschtyGdańsk",
  "80-339","Grunwaldzka","Gdańsk","80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk",
  "80-399","Grunwaldzka","dansk","80-399Grunwaldzkadańsk",
  "80-318","Wasowicza","Gdańsk","80-318WasowiczaGdańsk",
  "80-625","Stryjewskiego","Gdańsk","80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk",
  "80-625","Stryewskogo","Gdansk","80-625StryewskogoGdansk",
  "80-452","Kilinskiego","Gdańsk","80-452KilinskiegoGdańsk")

library(fuzzyjoin)

noise_df %>% 
  # using jaccard with max_dist=0.5. Try other distance methods with different max_dist to save memory use
  stringdist_left_join(dict_df, by="Adres", distance_col="dist", method="jaccard", max_dist=0.5) %>%
  select(Adres.x, ID, Adres.y, dist) %>% 
  group_by(Adres.x) %>% 
  # select best fit record
  top_n(-1, dist)
```

Results table consists of original address (`Adres.x`) and best match from the dictionary (`ID` and `Adres.y`) together with string distance.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Adres.x [10]
                         Adres.x     ID                      Adres.y       dist
                           <chr>  <chr>                        <chr>      <dbl>
 1          80-221TraugutaGdansk  33854        80-221TrauguttaGdańsk 0.11764706
 2         80-211TrauggutaGdansk  33854        80-221TrauguttaGdańsk 0.11764706
 3  80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk 157093 80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk 0.00000000
 4 80-276KsBernardaSyschtyGdańsk 157093 80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk 0.00000000
 5       80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk 200115      80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk 0.00000000
 6        80-399Grunwaldzkadańsk 200115      80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk 0.00000000
 7         80-318WasowiczaGdańsk 344514        80-318WąsowiczaGdańsk 0.05555556
 8     80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk 355415    80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk 0.00000000
 9       80-625StryewskogoGdansk 355415    80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk 0.17391304
10       80-452KilinskiegoGdańsk 356414      80-452KilińskiegoGdańsk 0.05263158
```

I found fuzzy match work best when you convert everything to lower case ASCII (`iconv()` and `tolower()`)

UPDATE: This might have smaller memory footprint:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
  noise_df %>% split(.$Adres) %>% 
  # using jaccard with max_dist=0.5. Try other distance methods with different max_dist to save memory use
  map_df(~stringdist_left_join(.x, dict_df, by="Adres", distance_col="dist", method="jaccard", max_dist=0.5, ignore_case = TRUE) %>%
          select(Adres.x, ID, Adres.y, dist) %>% 
          group_by(Adres.x) %>% 
          # select best fit record
          top_n(-1, dist))
```

UPDATE2: when using "lv" distance algorithm you get too many missing values and NAs. In certain cases, when no match is found, `string_dist_join` drops the `distance` column you created. That's why the rest of the pipe fails, first at `select` and later at `top_n`. In order to see whats going on, take small sample of your data, change `map_df` to `map` and explore resulting list.

Comment: Thanks, this function seems very interesting indeed. I have trouble though, understanding why it returns more rows than I want to. My sample has 614 rows, I have as many rows in the result of my original code, but this one (adapted for my use) returns 1196 rows: `test <- tableA %>% 
  stringdist_left_join(tableB1, by="Adres", distance_col="dist", method="lv", max_dist=99, ignore_case = TRUE) %>%
  select(Adres.x, Adres.y, dist) %>% 
  group_by(Adres.x) %>% 
  # select best fit record
  top_n(-1, dist)` Does it matter that I have removed ID (not having it in my original table)?

Comment: Do you have duplicates in Komb_ulic1$Adres, after converting it to lower case?

Comment: I haven't, so far I haven't had any issues with cases, as long as I specified that the function shouldn't be case-sensitive. Here for example, it correctly returns distance 0 where the only difference is the upper/lower case. Now I have also added IDs to the original addresses, as this might be useful later on.

Comment: It seems that in the original tableB some addresses are occuring several times, so fixing this should be easy.

Comment: After removing those duplicates I found that it returns more rows if within the same minimal distance two matches are found (only issue with bigger max_dist values). Also, even though it is much better optimized than the previous one, still there is a memory issue - previous required 1897.0 Gb allocation, this one "only" 326.2 Gb, regardless of max_dist setting. Any idea how can I optimize it further?

Comment: Do it one row at a time and force garbage collection. Will suggest revised code later tonight

Comment: Thanks, the improvement in memory usage is great (now when running it my computer uses 3GB instead of 7,5GB RAM), though I have one problem - with jaccard method it works fine (though slow), but when I switch to Levenshtein (lv), it returns error: `Error: dist must resolve to integer column positions, not a function`

Comment: It seems that when wrapped with map_df, "dist" inside is read as function name instead of column. When I replace it with "d" for example (in both lines of code), I get another error: `Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'd' not found` This seems very strange for me, as apart from adding map_df, there are no other changes compared to earlier code.

Comment: And finally if I remove "dist" from Select (just keeping it in the earlier line), there is another error `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'` All only when changed to Levenshtein, with Jaccard no such problems.

Comment: levinstein distance calcualtion fails (for whatever reason). I added some explanation how to diagnose whats going on.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. By the way, how can Levenshtein return NA, considering the max distance calculated should be just the number of characters in the longer string (if you do operation on every single one)?

Answer (score 0):

I have written an R package, [zoomerjoin](https://github.com/beniaminogreen/zoomerjoin), which uses allows you to fuzzily join large datasets without having to compare all pairs of rows between the two dataframes. This means that you can merge moderately-sized (tens of millions of rows) dataframes in seconds or minutes on a modern data-science laptop without running out of memory.

Here's how I would use the package to join these dataframes:

```
devtools::install_github("beniaminogreen/zoomerjoin")
library(zoomerjoin)
library(dplyr)

dict_df <- tibble::tribble(
     ~ID,~Zipcode,~Street,~City,~Adres,
"33854","80-221","Traugutta","Gdańsk","80-221TrauguttaGdańsk",
"157093","80-276","KsBernardaSychty","Gdańsk","80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk",
"200115","80-339","Grunwaldzka","Gdańsk","80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk",
"344514","80-318","Wąsowicza","Gdańsk","80-318WąsowiczaGdańsk",
"355415","80-625","Stryjewskiego","Gdańsk","80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk",
"356414","80-452","Kilińskiego","Gdańsk","80-452KilińskiegoGdańsk") %>% 
  select(ID, Adres)

noise_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Zipcode,~Street,~City,~Adres,
  "80-221","Trauguta","Gdansk","80-221TraugutaGdansk",
  "80-211","Traugguta","Gdansk","80-211TrauggutaGdansk",
  "80-276","KsBernardaSychty","Gdańsk","80-276KsBernardaSychtyGdańsk",
  "80-267","KsBernardaSyschty","Gdańsk","80-276KsBernardaSyschtyGdańsk",
  "80-339","Grunwaldzka","Gdańsk","80-339GrunwaldzkaGdańsk",
  "80-399","Grunwaldzka","dansk","80-399Grunwaldzkadańsk",
  "80-318","Wasowicza","Gdańsk","80-318WasowiczaGdańsk",
  "80-625","Stryjewskiego","Gdańsk","80-625StryjewskiegoGdańsk",
  "80-625","Stryewskogo","Gdansk","80-625StryewskogoGdansk",
  "80-452","Kilinskiego","Gdańsk","80-452KilinskiegoGdańsk")

jaccard_left_join(dict_df,noise_df, threshold=.7)
```

I have used this package in production to join datasets with hundreds of millions of names without incurring a large memory overhead so I feel confident it can do the job for you, as long as you are content with using jaccard distance (the only metric supported).